# Can folder color be changed in QTreeView when QFilesystemModel displays drives?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, directory, qfilesystemmodel

Well I have been working on a Qt app where I need to display Filesystem using `QFilesystemModel`.I have been able to display it as expected.

**Code:**

```
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
model->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath())
tree->setModel(model);
```

This displays all drives inside QTreeView. But we all know by default, the color of the folders present inside each drive is **yellow**.

This is what i wanna change. Is there a way in Qt, where one can change the color of folder to **"Blue"**???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your QTreeView via a qt delegate. But if it is just for an icon, I think you can reimplement:

```
class MyQFileSystemModel : public QFileSystemModel {
public:
    QVariant data( const QModelIndex& index, int role ) const {

        if( role == Qt::DecorationRole ) { 
            return QVariant(QIcon(QPixmap("icon.png")));
        }

        return QFileSystemModel::data(index, role);
    }
};
```

To learn about delegate, I suggest you study the examples: [Spin box delegate](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html)

EDIT: you have to reimplement the method data from a QFileSystemModel, you must inherit from QFileSystemModel.

Then you do as before:

```
MyQFileSystemModel* model = new MyQFileSystemModel;
model->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath())
tree->setModel(model);
```

Comment: Yeah I just figured out i have to do that. I would appreciate if Can you help me out with it please :)

Comment: Well I reconstructed my app according to what you said above..... I also put the Resource file and the path inside QPixMap. But when i run the app, folders are no more visible in the drivers inside QTreeView. I also found the `data()` is getting called n number of times. Whats the issue? :)

Comment: I can not compile it right now, I edited my answer it should work better. Data is called N times this is normal, it is called for each role for each item in your treeview.

Comment: Thanks buddyyyy... I made it work :) I cannot upvote since I have reputation less than 15 :(

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the workaround is to use your own [fileIcon](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfilesystemmodel.html#fileIcon).

Qt uses whatever the default icon is for the current platform. I'm guessing you're on Windows.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246984/how-to-override-re-implement-a-member-function-in-qfilesystemmodel) provides some clues on how to implement.

(I just started learning Qt myself, BTW!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply brother. yes I am using windows itself. I havent used FileIcon till now. Can you elaborate a bit more on it say via a sample code please :)