# How to show progress bar from a function in model?

Tags: c++, qt, progress-bar

I have function, `export()` in my `QFileSystemModel` derived class. Now I want to show progress bar as this function does it work. I obvioulsy don't want to popup `QProgressDialog`from there since GUI should be seperate.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonConvert_clicked()
{
    QString rootPath = ui->lineEditSourceFolder->text();

    QString destPath = ui->lineEditDestFolder->text();

    dirModel->convert(rootPath, destPath); // dirModel is QFileSystemModel derived member variable
}
```

Before moving `convert()` to model, it was in my `MainWindow` class. This function itself was creating `QProgressDialog` but now after moving to mode, it should be prohibited from creating it so where do I create the progress?

I got a hint from another post that I should be using signal and slots but how here?

Answer (score 1):

You should move `dirModel` to a new thread in order to prevent `export()` from blocking main thread and the UI. This can be done like:

```
QThread * th = new QThread();
dirModel->moveToThread(th);

QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(started()),dirModel,SLOT(OnStarted()));
QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(finished()),dirModel,SLOT(OnFinished()));

th->start();
```

Your initialization and termination tasks in `dirModel` should be done in `OnStarted()` and `OnFinished()` slots respectively.

You should use a signal in your class to notify the progress bar in the user interface of the value for the progress. In your `export()` function you should emit the signal with the appropriate value. The signal is like:

```
void progressChanged(int val);
```

You should also connect the `progressChanged(int)` signal to the `setValue(int value)` slot of the `QProgressBar`.

And the last point is that you should not call `export()` directly when it is in an other thread. The correct way is defining `export()` as a slot and connecting a signal to that slot and emitting the signal when you want to call `export()`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this could solve other issues I faced, like my internet connection was down the other day and the application wouldn't start for long long time because it was not able to find the mapped drive.